# What's the safest and quickest way of encrypting a password if I migrate a website?

Tags: php, password-encryption

Can you advise on the quickest way I could encrypt a password and keep it secure? And is there a way to transfer it? (I need PHP encryption)

What I want is to probably migrate the site to another server and I wanna know if all the passwords will still be functioning?

Comment: Are your passwords currently stored in plaintext? You do not want to encrypt your passwords, you want to _hash_ them using `password_hash()`. Unlike encryption, hashing is not reversible, and is the proper way to store passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what the passwords are used for, maybe you could explain a bit more.

1. They are user passwords used to authenticate the users, then they should be hashed with [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Most other languages offer similar hash functions, especially when used with the parameter PASSWORD_BCRYPT.
2. They are used to login e.g. to a database, then they could be encrypted, but this leads to question of how to store the key. It depends on the target system how safe you can store those passwords.